# Equation of tangent

Tags: geometry

I'm learning tangent equations and I need some help.

I am stuck on these few examples and I'm not sure what to do!

The examples are the following.

1. What is the equation of the tangent and normal of:

   a.) curve $y=2x^2-x-3$ with intersection point in $x$-axis

   b.) curve $x^2+y^2+4x-3y-4=0$ with intersection point in $y$-axis.
2. Write the equation of the tangent of the curve $y=x^3-2x^2$ which is:

   a.) parallel with the line $y=4x-3$

   b.) perpendicular to  the bisector of the first and third quadrant $(y=x).$
3. Write the equation of the tangent of the curve $y=x^2-7x$ which is parallel with the line $y=5x+2$.

Comment: I tried something, finding Xo, but didn't work well unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Or at least tell us what tools should you be using?

Comment: What I tried is the following. 1. a) we know that y=0, since it's intersection point is in x-axis, so we have to do, 2x^2-x-3=0, and get x1/2=3/2 and -1, which gives A(-1,0) and B(3/2,0). But then again I'm not sure if this is correct, and I solved this given on an example task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

$$2x^2-x-3=0\implies \Delta=b^2-4ac=1+24=5^2\implies$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm 5}{4}=\begin{cases}\;\frac{3}{2}\\{}\\\!\!-1\end{cases}$$

Say we choose the point $\,(-1,0)\,$ . To have the slope of the tangent line we need the derivative:

$$y'=4x-1\implies y'(-1)=-2$$

So the tangent line at $\,(-1,0)\,$ is $\,y-0=(-2)(x+1)\implies y=-2x-2\,$

The normal at $\,(-1,0)\,$ is a line passing through this point **and perpendicular** to the tangent, so its slope is $\,\frac{1}{2}\,$ , and this it is

$$y-0=\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\implies y=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}$$

Do the same with the other example, though in (1)-(b) for ex. you'll have to differentiatie implicitly to get the derivative, say:

$$2x\,dx+2y\,dy+4\,dx-3\,dy=0\implies(2y-3)dy=-(2x+4)dx\implies $$

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x+4}{3-2y}$$

In order to find the slope input the values of the tangent point and etc.

Comment: Sorry if I may ask, I got the slope to be 3/2 and also the answer to be y-0=-5(x+1). Do you mind if you check what am I doing wrong? I wrong the way I did in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you completely, but I think you simply chose to work with *the other* point of intersection. I chose  $\,(-1,0)\,$ , you chose $\,(3/2,0)\,$ ...

Comment: So, it doesn't matter which one I work with, the result I get with any is correct. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, I *think* the intention of the question is to do what I did with **both** intersection points...

Comment: You did great, it helped me a lot, I'm sorry for confusing you. Appreciate your help.